# Query for all documents in a database and not any specific collection in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I want to search and update any document which matches a particular id but dont want to specify any specific collection but the search needs to query all the documents in a particular database.

kind of db.find() not db.collection.find();

Any command which I may have overlooked in mongoose that accomplishes this?

Comment: You really should consider having a single collection of all `id`s that maps an `id` to a collection. Or consider using an `id` that contains a collection identifier embedded in the `id`.

Comment: Note that different documents with the same _id can be in multiple collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a db.find(). _id's are only unique in a specific collection. You can have different documents with different content but the same _id in different collections.

But what you can do is get a list of all collections using `db.getCollectionNames()` and query each of them.

By the way: I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but it really smells to me. Collections should be used to group objects which belong into a specific context. When you don't know the collection of an object you are searching for, you likely are doing something wrong.